# Merging queries with common group by parameters

Tags: sql

I have three SQL queries built, which act on a set of about eight tables.   Each of the three has the same parameter in its group by clause.   I'm trying to merge the three queries, to generate a single output table, though everything I try seems to break the working base queries.

I would like an output that looks like;

```
[heading] [query1 output column] [query2 output column] [query3 output column]
```

with the [heading] column being the existing parameter used in the group by clause for the three existing queries.

I realize I'm demonstrating my newbness here, though I'm stuck, and have gone around in the same erroneous circle way too many times....

EDIT  ***

I thought the code snip would be confusing, though here's a slightly abbreviated version;

```
SELECT 
TITLE_COUNT.index, 
COUNT  (TITLE_COUNT.TTOTAL) AS TITLES,
COUNT (AUTHOR_COUNT.TTOTAL) AS AUTHOR
FROM(
    SELECT 
    index, title, date,
    COUNT (*) AS TTOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT index, title, date FROM TableP P) P
    GROUP BY
    index, title, date
    ORDER BY
    index
) AS TITLE_COUNT,
(
    SELECT 
    index, 
    COUNT (*) AS TTOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT index, FROM TableM M) M
    GROUP BY
    index
    ORDER BY
    index
) AS AUTHOR_COUNT
WHERE
TITLE_COUNT.index = AUTHOR_COUNT.index
GROUP BY
TITLE_COUNT.index
;
```

My problem with the above is, the count columns in the output tables have been multiplied.   For example, stand along the queries give me something like

```
TITLE
index count
001     12
002     10
003     15

AUTHOR
index  count
001    2
002    4
003    6
```

Though my query above results in

```
001    24
002    40
003    90
```

Comment: Start by posting the SQL code you have.

Comment: Use case when and SUM function. Google for denormalizaion in SQL

Comment: when you post the queries, you should also post your attempts and errors with those.

Answer (score 0):

Don't double count:

```
SELECT 
TITLE_COUNT.index, 
TITLE_COUNT.TTOTAL AS TITLES,
AUTHOR_COUNT.TTOTAL AS AUTHOR
FROM(
    SELECT 
    index, title, date,
    COUNT (*) AS TTOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT index, title, date FROM TableP P) P
    GROUP BY
    index, title, date
    ORDER BY
    index
) AS TITLE_COUNT
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    index, 
    COUNT (*) AS TTOTAL
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT index, FROM TableM M) M
    GROUP BY
    index
    ORDER BY
    index
) AS AUTHOR_COUNT
   ON TITLE_COUNT.index = AUTHOR_COUNT.index
GROUP BY
    TITLE_COUNT.index
```